# Magento 1.9 - Add Product in New window

Tags: magento-1.9, product-grid

I want to open new window when I click "Add Product" button in `Catalog->Manage Products` grid.

[image: addproduct]

I want to enter new product details in new window not in existing window.

How to do that in Magento..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by

File path:

> magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product.php

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->_addButton('add_new', array(
            'label'   => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Add Product'),
            'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('*/*/new')}')",
            'class'   => 'add'
        ));

        $this->setChild('grid', $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_grid', 'product.grid'));
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

**Create a file and Replace function to:**

> magento/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product.php

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->_addButton('add_new', array(
            'label'   => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Add Product'),
            'onclick' => 'window.open(\''.$this->getUrl('*/*/new').'\')',
            'class'   => 'add'
        ));

        $this->setChild('grid', $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_grid', 'product.grid'));
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

replace `'window.open(\''.$this->getUrl('*/*/new').'\')'`

Enjoy :)

Comment: This is what exactly I need. it's working perfect. Thank you @Nikunj Vadariya..

Comment: Happy to help dear!